# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException in java while converting to MYSQL

Tags: java, mysql, exception, nullpointerexception

I am a beginner in Java and I am writing a code to input json twitter datasets into MYSQL database. I used a file name "file" as an input, parse it, and write it to SQL database. However, I keep getting the error:

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at edu.mbhs.twitter.test.main(test.java:42)**

Line 42 contains:

```
  if (tweet.getLang().equals("en")){
```

Here is my main class code:

```
public class test {

public static List <String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, InterruptedException, SQLException {

    JSONParser j = new JSONParser(new File("file"));
    ArrayList<Tweet> tweets = j.getTweets();


   String sql = "insert into twitterdatasets (tweet_created_at, tweet_id, tweet_text, user_id, user_screen_name, user_location, user_followers_count, user_friends_count, user_created_at, user_verified, user_lang, tweet_retweeted_count, tweet_favorite_count, tweet_lang) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
   Connection conn = getConnection();
   PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

   final int batchSize = 1000;
   int count = 0;

   for (Tweet tweet: tweets){

       if (tweet.getLang().equals("en")){
           User user = tweet.getUser();
           ps.setString(1, tweet.getCreatedAt());
           ps.setString(2, tweet.getIdStr());
           ps.setString(3, tweet.getText());
           ps.setString(4, user.getIdStr());
           ps.setString(5, user.getScreenName());
           ps.setString(6, user.getLocation());
           ps.setInt(7, user.getFollowersCount());
           ps.setInt(8, user.getFriendsCount());
           ps.setString(9, user.getCreatedAt());
           ps.setBoolean(10, user.getVerified());
           ps.setString(11, user.getLang());
           ps.setInt(12, tweet.getRetweetCount());
           ps.setInt(13, tweet.getFavoriteCount());
           ps.setString(14, tweet.getLang());
           ps.addBatch();
       if (++count % batchSize == 0){
           ps.executeBatch();
       }

       }
   }

   ps.executeBatch();
   ps.close();
   conn.close();
   System.out.println("File has been successfully written to database");
}

private static Connection getConnection() {
      Connection con = null;
      String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
      String db =  "dbo";
      String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
      String user = "root";
      String pass = "elvira03";
      try {
       Class.forName(driver);
       con = DriverManager.getConnection(url + db, user, pass);
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (SQLException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return con;
     }
}
```

Comment: line 42 is this:  if (tweet.getLang().equals("en")){

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
if(tweet.getLang()!= null && tweet.getLang().equals("en") { ... }
```

I think in some tweets language can be `null` if user didnt set it.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue using the Streaming API... turns out you get disconnected if your app processes messages too slow. The solution is to forego checking lang during message processing.

Instead, you can turn on a language filter in your OAuth params... I'm using scribe and this is what my solution looks like:

```
    OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder().provider(TwitterApi.class).apiKey("your_twitter_api_key")
                .apiSecret("your_twitter_api_secret").build();
    // Set your access token
    Token accessToken = new Token("your_twitter_token", "your_twitter_secret");
    // Let's generate the request
    System.out.println("Connecting to Twitter Public Stream");
    OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST, STREAM_URI);
    request.addHeader("version", "HTTP/1.1");
    request.addHeader("host", "stream.twitter.com");
    request.setConnectionKeepAlive(true);
    request.addHeader("user-agent", "Twitter Stream Reader");

        // ADD YOUR LANGUAGE PREFS HERE...
        request.addBodyParameter("language", "en");

    service.signRequest(accessToken, request);
    Response response = request.send();

    // Create a reader to read Twitter's stream
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getStream()));
```